# Sort terms aggregation results based on date they were first seen

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose the event occurrence is like the following

- eventA -10 AM
- eventB -11 AM
- eventA -12 AM

I need the `aggregation order` to be coming like

1. eventA (eventA is shown first because it came first)
2. eventB

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [ordering terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

You need `event_date` `sub-aggregation` in your `terms aggregation`

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "event_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event_name",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "first_arrive": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_event_occur": {
          "min": {
            "field": "event_date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```